# Internet access from inside docker over Oracle VM and cntlm proxy

Tags: docker, proxy, virtualbox, ubuntu-16.04

How can I make internet http calls from inside docker on Ubuntu 16.04 over Oracle VM (5.2.4) and cntlm proxy on Windows 7?

The Proxy is configured (IP 192.168.56.1, the VMs host). Internet access is successful within Ubuntus Firefox or with wget from commandline.

Docker CE (17.12.0-ce) is configured to use also the proxy ip:
/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf

```
[Service]
Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://192.168.56.1:3128/"
Environment="HTTPS_PROXY=http://192.168.56.1:3128/"
```

All docker images I could pull successful.

Only the wget or any install calls inside a docker container fails.

Many help pages later, I haven't no idea more.
My tries:

```
docker run --name test --network host -e "https_proxy=https://192.168.56.101:3128" -it alpine:latest wget https://www.web.de
wget: bad address 'www.web.de'

docker run --name test --dns 8.8.8.8 -e "https_proxy=https://192.168.56.101:3128" -it alpine:latest wget https://www.web.de
wget: bad address 'www.web.de'

docker run --name test -e "https_proxy=https://192.168.56.101:3128" -it alpine:latest wget https://www.web.de
wget: bad address 'www.web.de'

docker run --name test --network host --dns 8.8.8.8 -e "https_proxy=https://192.168.56.101:3128" -it alpine:latest wget https://www.web.de
wget: bad address 'www.web.de'
```

All the printed calls also with "http" and without the proxy Environment.

Another ideas for me?

Comment: Your proxy IP is 192.168.56.1, but you use 192.168.56.101?

Comment: It was a try, to overwrite the proxy config, but without success.

Comment: The VM host ist pingable from inside a docker container:

`docker run --name test --rm alpine:latest ping 192.168.56.1
PING 192.168.56.1 (192.168.56.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.56.1: seq=0 ttl=127 time=0.414 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.56.1: seq=1 ttl=127 time=0.345 MS`

But my Laptop self or an external address isn't reachable:

`docker run --name test --rm alpine:latest wget http://172.18.54.68
Connecting to 172.18.54.68 (172.18.54.68:80)
wget: can't connect to remote host (172.18.54.68): Network unreachable`

Comment: Internet access is only available outside the docker container:

`docker run --name test --rm alpine:latest wget http://www.web.de
wget: bad address 'www.web.de'
`

Comment: Ubuntus `/etc/resolv.conf` hasn't entries.

Comment: Würde ein zweiter Proxy innerhalb von Ubuntu das Problem lösen? Wie wäre dieser zu konfigurieren?

Comment: er... maybe English would be better.

Answer (score 0):

For docker to work with CNTLM it is important to set

```
Gateway yes
```

in the CNTLM-Config.

I run CNTLM directly on the VM and set all proxys within the container to http://172.17.0.1:3128.

For the sake of completeness, please set all Proxy-Env in **docker run**:

```
PROXY_DOCKER="http://172.17.0.1:3128/"
docker run -e HTTP_PROXY=${PROXY_DOCKER} -e http_proxy=${PROXY_DOCKER} -e HTTPS_PROXY=${PROXY_DOCKER} -e https_proxy=${PROXY_DOCKER} ...
```